# How to prioritize emacs completion sources?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

When auto completing inside a buffer, I've found that nearby words are not at that top of the list but I want them to be.

I'm using auto-complete right now, but I am open to using something else that can do comprehensive completion (combining many sources, such as words in buffer, project, programming language completion, etc.) and automatically displays candidates as I type.

I've read over documentation on auto-complete and company mode. The only thing I can find is turning sources on and off, but nothing about prioritizing them, which is what I want to do. I can imagine several ways to accomplish this, like altering these packages, or writing code to combine and prioritize sources, but it just seems like someone must have done this already.

Edit: I've tracked down part of the problem to the autocomplete source which is supposed to do completion for words in the buffer (ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers) not prioritizing words nearby, but the original question still stands.

Comment: The source you're referring to can't really do that because it would have to keep an updated location of everything you ever type in each major mode, which is completely unfeasible. You could define a different source which parses the words around point at the moment of completion, but which doesn't store a list of words anywhere. I don't know enough about sources to help you here, but the elisp part wild be something like `(cl-remove-if (lambda (candidate) (null (string-match word-being-completed candidate))) list-of-candidate-words)`. Good luck :-)

Comment: It's not "everything you ever type". Its words in my current buffer, which it already keeps an updated list of, and having location information as part of that is completely feasible imo.

Comment: I you're right, you could parse the buffer when it's open.

Comment: The problem is that text gets shifted around a lot as you write and edit. It's not just about inserting text at the end (that would be easy to track), it's about when you insert text in the middle. Then you'll have to find the 100s of words the list that are after the current point and update their positions, and you'll have to do that after every character inserted (or maybe every spacebar), which might introduce some lag.

Comment: This might be faster if you keep the list in buffer order (instead of alphabetical order, which makes completions easier to check) but then this list is just the buffer itself, and you might as well stop trying to keep track of it and just process the surrounding words at the time of completion (which is what I suggested at first :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto-complete prioritizes by previously completed completions and then by shortest completion. It could be altered in the auto-complete source, or a function combining sources and prioritizing them could be written.

Hippie completion is closer to solving the problem; it prioritizes sources by their order in a list, and it has a completion source of words nearby in the form of "visible words." It does not have an automatic completion UI, but it could be hooked into auto-complete.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs's built-in dabbrev-expand function is worth experimenting with.  The function is automatically bound to M-/ in standard modes.

Comment: Dabbrev is not comprehensive, and not what I am after. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Dabbrev searches within buffers from the current point in a non-discriminatory fashion, e.g. collecting results from not just nearby code but from comments and from other buffers which may be in any major mode. For me that is sufficiently comprehensive.